# Sum of child of child in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, master-detail

I need help in LINQ query in EF6.

the master table is called `EXAM`. its child is `ExamResult`.
each `ExamResult` has a `Question` and the selected `Answer`.
each `Answer` has `power` (0 if wrong, 1 if correct).
if I want to know the total of correct answers, I simply run the command:

```
var examTotal = db.Exams.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ExamID == examId).ExamResults.Sum(er => er.Answer.Power);
```

my problem is when some questions were not answered, and I get `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general nullchecks should do the trick

```
var exam = db.Exams.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ExamID == examId);
var examTotal = exam.ExamResults.Sum(er => er.Answer?.Power ?? 0);
```

...and just in case you're not using C# 6, here's Another version of it:

```
var exam = db.Exams.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ExamID == examId);
var examTotal = exam.ExamResults.Sum(er => er.Answer != null ? er.Answer.Power : 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple problems with your "command".

First off, there are at least **two** queries:

(1) `var exam = db.Exams.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ExamID == examId);`

(2) `var examTotal = exam.ExamResults.Sum(er => er.Answer.Power);`

Note that the second really executes inside the LINQ to Objects context (eventually including some hidden db calls due to lazy loading).
In that context, there are 2 possible places that can raise NRE

(A) `exam.ExamResults` if `exam` is null
(B) `er.Answer.Power`if `er.Answer` is null

You can fix them by including null checks as proposed in other answers.

But better way would be make your command execute a single query inside the LINQ to Entities context where navigation properties have different meaning:

```
var examTotal = db.Exams.Where(ex => ex.ExamID == examId)
    .SelectMany(ex => ex.ExamResults)
    .Sum(er => (int?)er.Answer.Power) ?? 0;
```

The only trick needed is to project the field you want to sum to a **nullable** type (I've used `int?` assuming the `Power` field is of `int` type, change it to your type if different). This is letting the EF to always return the `Sum` regardless of whether `er.Answer` is null or `ex.ExamResults` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var examTotal = db.Exams.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ExamID == examId).ExamResults.Where(er => er.Answer != null).Sum(er => er.Answer.Power);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var examTotal = db.Exams.FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.ExamID == examId).ExamResults.Count(er => er.Answer.Power == 1);
```

This will not use the value but instead see if it is equal to 1, thus not generate any `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: For sure I will get the `NullReferenceException` since the null is in having an answer and not in having a power for the answer. in other words, I may have a question without answer, but if answered, I cannot have an answer without power.

Comment: @omarmallat Sorry, missed that it was the case for `Answer` being null.... So stupid of me..